# What is a hypersurface?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, terminology, definition

What is the concept of [hypersurface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersurface) in general relativity? I know it could be characterized into three categories but how do we define hypersurface (in general) in physics? I didn't get what thing it is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersurface

Comment: A hypersurface in a manifold $M$ is a codimension one embedded submanifold $\Sigma\subset M$. This means that $\Sigma$ has one dimension less than $M$. For example, if $M$ were three-dimensional, a hypersurface would be two-dimensional, i.e., a standard surface. If $M$ were four-dimensional a hypersurface would be three-dimensional and so on.

Comment: For example the [hypersurface of simultaneity](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/relative.simultaneity.html) is the whole volume of the universe right now, which is velocity dependent.

Comment: Shouldn't it have been called a _hyposurface_ instead, as it is "sub-dimensional"?  Hyper implies an _extra_ dimension (from my chemistry days).

Comment: @m4r35n357 I think maybe the hyper here means higher than two dimensions as usually a surface is just a two-dimensional plane.

Comment: @DavidShaw Except that in 2D space a "hypersurface" is a (one-dimensional) curve (from the wikipedia article above, second paragraph).